# How many weapon schematics are there in Fallout New Vegas?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I want to know how many schematics there are in total in the game for Fallout new vegas as I am not sure how many weapons there are. if its at all possible could someone tell me the location of these schematics or link me to a page im on a personal errand to get all the constructible weapons in the game.

Comment: the 3 schematics thing was a fallout 3 thing.  FNV doesnt have that system.  Also, this link can help: http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_crafting

Comment: thanks I thought I might have been a bit muddled up with them they are so similar I've gave my question a little edit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fallout New Vegas doesn't really have a whole lot of *weapon* crafting, unless you're into Explosives and want to make bombs. In fact, without DLC, there's exactly **one** craftable weapon that isn't a bomb or mine -  [the Dog Tag Fist](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Dog_tag_fist), which you can make with a Repair skill of 30. The schematic can be had from Private Halford at Camp Guardian.

If you have *Dead Money*, you can do a few upgrades to the **Cosmic Knife**, turning it into the [Cosmic Knife Clean](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Cosmic_knife_clean) or it's [Super Heated variant](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Cosmic_knife_super-heated), or a [Knife Spear](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Knife_spear), which also has a [Clean version](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Knife_spear_clean). You'll need the Repair skill to make these, with 50 being the highest number required, but you don't need any special schematic.

With *Old World Blues* installed, the only craftable gun in the game becomes available, [FIDO](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/FIDO) is little more than an upgrade to the K-9000 Cyberdog Gun, and is one of the only two weapons for which you'll need a schematic. It's found in the kennel at the X-8 Research center. You'll also need a Guns skill of 75

Finally, *Lonesome Road* adds the [Fist of Rawr](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fist_of_Rawr). You'll get the schematic automatically when picking up the component parts after killing Rawr, and crafting this powerful fist weapon requires an Unarmed skill of 75.

As for bombs - very few need schematics. Most just need a high Explosives skill, and, in many cases, the **Mad Bomber** perk and the *Gun Runner's Arsenal* DLC. [You can view the full list of craftable items here.](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_crafting) In general, crafting in NV is much more geared towards chems, healing items, food, ammunition, and other consumables than it was in FO3. There are few, if any craftable 'durable goods' of any worth.

Comment: cheers that went into a lot more detail than i was expecting :)

Answer (score -3):

There are no "true" schematics in FNV that create weapons,you need certain skills to attain these schematics through console commands[PC] or use wild wasteland[all]to get named weapons unique like the Alien blaster,found North of the horowitz farmstead at the northern end of the game/road to jakobstown,North of NV,just look to the right at the intersected roads to the barn in the sand,North is the Flying anomaly[wild wasteland] or a merc camp[hostile] with the ycs/186 gausse rifle.